# Current status of Page Curl

Tags: ipad, animation

There have been alot of questions regarding page curl animations on ipad and lately more and more applications have been including this.

I have seen links to two projects on github which implement this animation ([here](https://github.com/jemmons/PageCurl) and [here](https://github.com/brow/leaves)) but none of these (e.g. kindle) seem to be near to the ibooks (except for the 'Target' app) - yet better than the ones on github.

Are there any newer solutions out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a Page Curl like filter using OpenGL and CoreGraphics. Speaking about math, shadow casting, shader etc. was a nightmare :-) but it's realistic and it's very close to the iBooks one.

http://api.mutado.com/mobile/paperstack/

I'm working on an easy-to-use API to integrate the GLView and other classes in a common project (like a PDF viewer).

To resume, the logic behind is based on a conical page deformation but to be realistic like iBooks, the math is quite different from the [Nuon conical deformation](http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html). The filter is done, I hope to complete the API it in a couple of weeks then I'll publish it on github.

Comment: How are things going with the paperstack api? Any news on when it will be available in GitHub?

Comment: We released the alpha source code to reveal the math and geometry behind the curl

Comment: I'm building a PDF reader right now and this looks like it's going to be just what I need. I currently have my project built with Leaves but it's creating CGImages out of the PDF pages which is making it really slow. Any update on that easy to use API for PaperStack? Your hard work is appreciated!