# Page curl & turn effects for iPhone Development

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, curl, uiviewanimation, ibooks

I'm looking for a very simple page turn effect, similar to the one in iBooks BUT much simpler. I only need the page to be turned if the user swipes the screen (so no difficult 'grabbing' the page animations etc. -- simply an animation). Actually, all I would need is the following with the exception that it should not CurlDown or CurlUp, but from the left side to the right side and vice versa:

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:
         UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                               forView:self.view cache:YES];
```

I had a look around an there are several tutorials on how to do more advanced page turns:

---

For iOS 5: Simply use UIPageViewController (see edit below)

For iPad: [Page Curling](http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html) -- looks perfect & beautiful, but quite advanced

For iPad: [Page Curling](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/) -- right direction, but not as beautiful

For iPhone: [Fancy 'Transparent' Curl (like iBooks)](http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html) -- private API though (?)

Deconstructing the effect in Classics: [Classics App](http://darknoon.com/blog/2008/12/08/deconstructing-classicsapp/)

---

I guess there may be more tutorials and sample code and I was wondering if we could collect them here with a little description. And of course, I am particularly looking for that very simple page-turn effect similar to `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown/Up`, only that it goes from right-to-left and not buttom-to-top.

Would it be easy to achieve a simple page turn effect with gradient overlays and a little 2-D animation? Or is this what the 'leaves' project is all about? Thanks for clarifications and updates of the list.

---

EDIT:

With iOS 5 you can now easily add iBooks like page turn effects. Simply open a new project and choose Page-based Application (you need xCode 4.2 and iOS 5 running).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339917/current-status-of-page-curl/6449522#6449522) about the status of Page Curl effect.

We worked on a filter based on OpenGL ES and CoreGraphics that looks really close to the iBooks one and it's App Store safe. The filter is finished, we're working on a simple and easy-to-use API to integrate the effects.

Take a look here http://api.mutado.com/mobile/paperstack/

Comment: Wow, looks really good. Will this be for the iPhone as well? Thanks for the good work. I guess that even with iOS 5 there will be no API for page curl available... I guess that were iOS 5 to include a page curl API you would stop developing one, right?

Comment: Thank you! It works with iOS 3.0+ iPhone and iPad. iOS 5 include some feature to use page curl as transition and control the half-transition or partial transition but I'm still trying to understand if the full-finger control will be available in iOS 5 (I mean the possibility to change the deformation according to the touch points)... if yes, paperstack was a nice "experience" but we will stop the development :-)

Comment: amazing! as i said, i really like your project. and whether or not iOS will enable finger control, you should be proud of what you've achieved so far.

Comment: don't want to depress you, but have you seen this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeAVv8BSOr8

Comment: Yes :-) I tried it with iOS5! Finally! Would be nice to have the API based on iOS5 and a fallback to paperstack if iOS < 5 :-)

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking about this. I'm sure not everyone will (or will be able) to update to iOS 5. So there is definitively a need for paperstack. How far are you with the project? I just submitted an App which uses my own hand-made page-turn effect (with shades etc.) - If you like, I can send you a promo code once it's on the store. All the best!

Comment: We're working on the API but because of iOS5, could be nice to release an API with the complete workflow (iOS5 flip+paperstack fallback)... Anyway, we're also working on an HMTL5 porting (based on WebGL) to create an iBooks like application based on paperstack. I'm thinking about to publish all the stuff on github and start a "dev request" to find people to develop paperstack+HTML5 version in a collaborative way...

Answer (score 4):

you can try XBPageCurl project , its more mature than using paperstack and free
https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl